# Web-based VS code run in browser

Tags: visual-studio-code, web-ide

Since VS code is built with electron, it's hard to run VS code in browser.

I saw there's a project (https://github.com/spiffcode/ghedit) making thing for that. But it's out of date. Is there any other active projects doing the same thing?

Or is there any other web-based IDE including file explorer, tab management, and git version control?

Comment: Electron is meant for creating desktop applications using web technologies. Why would you want to run a desktop app back in the browser? Perhaps I'm not understanding your question.

Comment: I want to implement a web-based IDE. This is what [spiffcode/ghedit](https://github.com/spiffcode/ghedit) did. ghedit remove the dependency of  electron in VS code. It did a great job, but it seems not maintained.

Comment: see [How can I host VS Code for browser based remote access?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71046228/11107541)

Answer (score 6):

https://github.com/cdr/code-server

This project allows you to run vscode in the browser.

Answer (score 5):

The editor component of VSCode, called [Monaco](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/), runs in the browser.

[Sourcegraph](https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/Microsoft/vscode/-/blob/src/vs/editor/editor.all.ts#L21:41) is also based on VSCode. It's not really an editor though, as files are read-only and it's used for viewing the contents of GitHub repositories.

Comment: Monaco is just an editor. VS code is IDE. Monaco is just a component of VS code. Sourcegraph is an read-only IDE, but it's not open sourced.

Comment: I know, that's why I called it "editor component". ;) Your question didn't make it clear that you already knew about Monaco and Sourcegraph.

Answer (score 5):

One option is Cloud9.  It's open source:

https://github.com/c9/core

I've written [some instructions on how to use it](https://arnisandy.wordpress.com/2016/02/14/cloud9-edit-your-code-from-anywhere/) as it can be a bit finicky.

One VSCode-based web editor to keep an eye on is [Theia](http://www.theia-ide.org).  There are [docker images available](https://github.com/theia-ide/theia-apps#theia-docker) to give it a whirl.

Answer (score 3):

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/), Online VS Code IDE for Angular & React.

Answer (score 2):

Also checkout https://github.com/theia-ide/theia

You run it on a remote server, and it provides you essentially a cut-down, self-hosted version of vs-code, that is accessible in the browser:

You can give it a try extremely quickly with docker:

```
docker run -it --init -p 3000:3000 -v "$(pwd):/home/project:cached" theiaide/theia:next
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to host the editor yourself, you can try https://gitpod.io. It integrates well with GitHub, and you can add language support through custom Docker file.

GitPod uses Theia internally.

Answer (score 1):

MS Just announced VS code for the web called [Visual Studio Online](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/announcing-visual-studio-online-public-preview/)