# How can I host VS Code for browser based remote access?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

Like Eclipse Theia, is it possible to run VS Code centrally, so it can be accessed remotely via browser (in multi-user scenarios using)? I am NOT talking about "https://vscode.dev/" (I am aware of that). I am curious about private hosting, with custom plugins, etc. (like Eclipse Theia).

Comment: there is https://github.com/coder/code-server but its kind of mute when you can use the [remote extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/remote-overview) to connect over ssh

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou @lawrence-Cherone [coder.com](https://coder.com/)

[image]

if you are using **Docker**

1. simply create *docker-compose.yml*

[image]

2. run `docker-compose up` in cmd

[image]

```
    version: "2.1"
services:
  code-server:
    image: lscr.io/linuxserver/code-server
    container_name: code-server
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - TZ=Europe/London
      - PASSWORD=password #optional
      - HASHED_PASSWORD= #optional
      - SUDO_PASSWORD=password #optional
      - SUDO_PASSWORD_HASH= #optional
      - PROXY_DOMAIN=code-server.my.domain #optional
      - DEFAULT_WORKSPACE=/config/workspace #optional
    volumes:
      - /path/to/appdata/config:/config
    ports:
      - 8443:8443
    restart: unless-stopped
```

3. After Completing your **IDE** available in localhost:8443 (As mentioned in the dockercompose.yml)

For more information visit [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxserver/code-server)

---

Installing on Windows (use git bash):

> Windows
> We currently do not publish Windows releases. We recommend installing code-server onto Windows with yarn or npm.
>
> Note: You will also need to build coder/cloud-agent manually if you would like to use code-server --link on Windows.
> [Document](https://coder.com/docs/code-server/latest/install#windows)

[image]

```
    yarn global add code-server
# Or: npm install -g code-server
code-server
# Now visit http://127.0.0.1:8080. Your password is in ~/.config/code-server/config.yaml
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just run `code serve-web --host=<host-to-listen-on> --port=<port-to-listen-on>`. you can see the help menu for `code serve-web` by running `code serve-web --help`. It defaults to localhost, but you should be able to pass it a host and public port to listen on, assuming you've configured your system firewall to open one up.

Another possible option should be to use [VS Code Server](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/vscode-server) by running `code tunnel` and pass arguments of choice; see help with `code tunnel --help`), which "*[creates] a tunnel that's accessible on vscode.dev from anywhere*" (see also the [vscode.dev docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/vscode-web)).

Side-note, if you want to test a web VS Code extension you're developing, see https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/web-extensions#test-your-web-extension.